# Ajax api call table population

Tags: html, ajax

I am able to display api response in a single  tag in an html table. However, I am trying to add another piece of the response into the table. I have hit the wall...

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "api query url",
auth: "user:password",
dataType: "json",
crossDomain: true,
success: function(data) {
var list = data.list;
$.each(list, function(i, item) {
var tr = $('<tr>').append($('<td>').text(item.name));
```

This is where I get stuck...

```
$('<tr>').append($('<td>').text(item.playerStatus)); 
$("#scalaapi").append(tr);
});
}
})
```

Here is a sample of the json response...

```
{
"list": [
    {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "Scala_Test Player",
        "playerStatus": "Active",
        "uuid": "f5672f69-be76-4057-8a46-68fa4ba9dda8",
        "previewPlayer": false,
        "enabled": true,
        "mac": "00-00-00-00-00-00",
        "type": "CHROMEBOX",
        "distributionServer": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Main",
            "driver": "IP_P2P"
        },
    }
}
```

And HTML...

```
<section class="reports">
<div id="output">
    <table id="scalaapi">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are initializing variable tr in loop. Hence its assigning new value to it and erasing old values. Declare it outside for each loop.

Please try below

```
$.each(val, function(i, item) {

       tr = $('<tr>').append('<td>' + (item.name) + '</td>' + 
                             '<td>' + (item.playerStatus) + '</td>');

       $("#scalaapi").append(tr);
  });
```

Here is link to [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/webireluxi/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Could you explain how to do this?

Comment: @KevMoe Please try New answer.

Comment: Thank you... Though this does not solve my problem of populating a second <td> with playerStatus.

Comment: Could u please provide json data

Comment: I have added some of the json response

Comment: But that is just single record. Hope u have more in actual json. So u r able to print only one?

Comment: Can u also put html in ur question?

Comment: Thank you for your help... I have added the html.  I took just one record, I am attempting to display "name" and "playerStatus" in the same row for each record.

Comment: i have updated answer and added link to show you output. let me know if that is what you want